# Facebook-Graph: Getting pageid of FBPage returns Graph error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm currently working on a facebook app using PHP and JS. In an external part of my app (it is an admin panel), which is NOT inside the facebook app itself, I want to admin registered "users". In my case every user is one single facebook page.

What I'd like to do now is get the fbpage pageid only from the url of the fbpage. I read several tuts and the easiest solution seems to be just to replace the `www`in the url with `graph`. For Coca Colas page for example this works just fine: [Graph Coca Cola](https://graph.facebook.com/coca-cola)
So Coca Cola's fb page pageid is `40796308305`.

When I do this for some random [Hotel page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hotel-Des-Balances/302383665689) now, I get an error: [Graph Hotel page](https://graph.facebook.com/pages/Hotel-Des-Balances/302383665689)

Yes I do realize that the hotel's pageid is already in the url in this case (`302383665689`) but I would like to implement this pretty fail safe as this is not always the case with facebook's weird urls! :-/

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I want to avoid using full facebook oAuth process and all that since the pageid is the only thing I need.

Any ideas on this? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The url https://graph.facebook.com/302383665689 works for me ( as you know it would ).

Am I correct by saying you only get an error for pages who do not have a "custom url"? Like the coca-cola one? If that is the case, then you should already have an id for all urls that do not work ( as facebook uses those to identify the page ), much like the hotel page.

Can you first detect the id in the url? Or replace anything from https://graph.facebook.com/ up to the first digit and then use that url to grab the page info from the graph-api?

If I'm wrong saying you should have i'd for pages without a custom url, please provide an url that doesn't work and for which you do not have an ID yet.

( I'm sorry for asking questions in here, as I cannot comment on your question yet because I do not have 50 rep yet... )